# Why does loading multiple pgfplotslibraries in the same command sometime break the libraries?

Tags: pgfplots, statistics

I'm making some boxplots with the pgf statistics library. And I found the following.

This:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

%Loading the libraries the other way around gives the same result
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction = y,
    ]
        \addplot [boxplot] table [col sep=comma,y index=0] {datatest.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this:
[image]

But this (I'm now including `fillbetween` and `statistics` in the same `\usepgfplotslibrary` command):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,statistics}

%Loading the libraries the other way around gives the same result
%\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics,fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction = y,
    ]
        \addplot [boxplot] table [col sep=comma,y index=0] {datatest.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]
Where the outlier is not marked.

Why does loading two libraries in the same statement break one? Thx for the help ;-)

edit, sorry I forgot the test file:

datatest.txt:

```
1
1
2
1
1
3
5
```

I also did test this both with `\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics,fillbetween}` and `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,statistics}` both produce the wrong result. At the same time, both

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
```

and

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
```

produce the right result.

Comment: what is in the datatest.txt?

Comment: btw: the problem is quite probably the *order* how you load the libraries, but without a test file it is difficult to test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I'm really sorry I forgot the datafile, it's there now ;-) I did test with loading the libraries in both orders (both with them in the same command and in seperate commands), the result was the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition `\use@@pgfplotslibrary` has at the end this piece of code

```
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pgfp@library@#1@loadoptions\endcsname\relax
    \else
        \expandafter\let\expandafter\pgfplots@glob@TMPa\csname pgfp@library@\pgf@temp @loadoptions\endcsname
        \expandafter\pgfplotsset\expandafter{\pgfplots@glob@TMPa}%
    \fi
```

Its purpose is to load "library hook code". In the case of the statistic library it should execute `\csname pgfp@library@statistics@loadoptions\endcsname` which basically does

```
/pgfplots/compat/library hook={statistics}{/pgfplots/boxplot/estimator=Excel,/pgfplots/boxplot/ensure mark=true},
```

where the `ensure mark=true` gives your mark.

The problem is that `#1` is `statistics,fillbetween` or `fillbetween,statistics` if you combine both in one command, and so the test is always false.

So it is a bug but simply replacing `#1` by `\pgf@temp` *does not work*, as these library calls can be nested and so the value is not correct in all cases.

Comment: So this means that any pgfplotslibrary that needs a hook would fail if you load them at once? this seems like a fairly big problem, but I see that it's already been reported, thanks for the help 8-)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the reputation to comment. So I am writing an "answer". The difference is that different files get loaded. When you say

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,statistics}
```

you load

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfcontrib/tikzlibraryfillbetween.code.tex
```

whereas with

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
```

you load

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.fillbetween.code.tex
```

All the paths refer to my TeXLive installation, but the exact names of the paths do not matter.

As far as I can see this has to do with `\pgfplots@iffileexists`, which gets called by `\use@@pgfplotslibrary`. It appears that you are in a "wrong" subdirectory when this check is performed.

So IMHO the bottomline is that you have found an issue, which you may want to report on [this site](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think Ulrikes answer was a better explanation of the phenomenon, but seeing this, as a more practical example, was also nice ;-)